# Why does boolean variable not show any result on false?

Tags: java, android, variables, boolean

I have tried to use a `boolean` variable in my `Activity`. I tried to check with `boolean` value if `true` and `false`. But I am only getting result for `false`.

```
private boolean editMode;


if(editMode) //false
    {

        delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Log","Edit mode");
    }
else //true
    {
        Log.i("Log1","Save mode");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Save mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Every time I am getting "Save mode". How can I check for both `true` and `false`?

I want to show one `Activity` with two modes. If it is "Save mode" I want to hide a button. If it's "Edit mode" the button should be visible.

I want the `boolean` variable `true` if I am clicking on my events.  So I tried to pass `boolean` variable as `true`.

```
eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
            editMode = true;
            i.putExtra("EditMode",editMode);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

So now every time it shows `true` value i.e "Edit mode". I only want it as "Edit mode" when I am clicking on 'eventView'. I have events and add button to go to 'add event' Activity. If going from 'add' button it should be "Save mode" or if with 'eventView' it should be "Edit mode".

How to do this?

Comment: If you are getting save mode then the variable is false...

Comment: the default value for boolean is false. Am I correct? @Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: `if(editMode)//false` **WRONG!** This means: `if(editMode == true) //false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare variable `editMode`, but you haven't assigned it with anything yet, so it'll always be true. To get data from `putExtra()`, you have to call `Intent.get__Extra()` in the activity you start.

In your  `add event activity`, write this:

```
private boolean editMode;
Intent i = getIntent();
editMode = i.getBooleanExtra("EditMode", true);
if(editMode)
....
```

Comment: yes i have done this. But I am getting always true. I want it false if I am clicking on add button. not event.

Comment: your code shows that you are setting it to true on click.  if you want false set it to false on your add button

Answer (score 1):

Negate your first check and you should be good

```
if(!editMode)//false
{

    delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edit mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("Log","Edit mode");
}
else//true
{
    Log.i("Log1","Save mode");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Save mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

That means if not editMode.  since editMode is a Boolean (a primitive type) it does not start off as null.  This means that it needs a default value, in this case that value is false.  Your code says if editMode is true log "Edit mode" otherwise log "Save mode

Comment: Thank you for answer.Please check my edited question. @aemorales1

Comment: Need to see the definition of your method which is doing the if check.

Comment: sorry which method? @aemorales1

Comment: where your if else is being performed, please see the answer from @NoImNotNull I'm pretty sure that will answer your question